# Good / Easy / free VPN solution you can use with OpenVZ

Tags: vpn, vps, openvz

I have a small VPS which is based on OpenVZ and TUN/TAP is enabled. I am trying to set up a small VPN but I am running in some problems.

The first thing I have tried is to set up the VPN using PPTP, but I came to the conclusion that it does not work with OpenVZ.

Now my ISP recommended OpenVPN, but when looking at the tutorial I have to pay for the service if the network grows bigger than 2 clients. Another downside with OpenVPN I think is that you need to download a whole package with installer to use it.

So my question is what the best way is to achieve the VPN that I am looking for.

My server is linux based (debian / centos / etc), and the computer I use to connect is a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it should be possible to achieve a PPTP vpn to your OpenVZ server. But I have bad experiences with PPTPD (you will have to install a package for the PPTP deamon too!) and a lot of good experiences with OpenVPN and the costs are tiny: 5USD for a extra concurrent connection. You could add as much clients as you want, when you stay under 3 concurrent connections, you don't need to pay anything. 
I recommend installing OpenVPN instead of PPTPD since OpenVPN requires no set-up on a client, just download an executable and you're good te go. Installing and troubleshooting OpenVPN is also a lot easier, since you're dealing with a nice webinterface.

Comment: Ok this is nice to know. But I see a lot of version of openvpn. I see that there are 2 websites: http://openvpn.se and http://openvpn.net. Which one should I go to to download the windows client.

Comment: I also see 2 different version on http://openvpn.net. I see conmmunity software and access server. Which one is the one I should use. I see that the community server is only free for 30 days.

Comment: You should get OpenVPN Access Server. You can download it here: http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run OpenVPN on OpenVZ, a good provider should be able to configure it. PM and I can send you some details.

Heck I don't know if it is okay to refer you from here.
I should find out soon enough

http://secure.quickweb.co.nz/system/aff.php?aff=015

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and it is ok to post links here. There is no PM here. But I have my VPS already, so I do not need to switch providers, I need some details on setting up the VPN.

Comment: Your provider has to setup the host system to allow the tunneling to work. If you use the Community version you can probably host as many as you system has the horsepower for.

Comment: If your provider is competent enough they be able to setup the host system to allow the tunneling to work.

If you use the Community version you can probably host as many as your system has the horsepower for. There are no charges on the Community edition

If you have the time to be patient enough to read the docs you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished installing PPTP VPN in openvz VPS, using Centos 5.5.. it works perfect for me... just use webmin and poptop PPTPD. with just few modification.

Comment: Is there a guide on doing this somewhere online?